# Why do I get floating point values in my weka output?

Tags: weka

I'm running the J48 algorithm on a dataset, and in the output I get something like this:

```
J48 pruned tree
------------------

attribute1 = n: class1 (253.41/3.75)
attribute1 = y
|   attribute2 = n: class2 (145.71/4.0)
|   attribute2 = n: class1 (40.68/3.0)
```

I'm wondering what the stuff in the parenthesis means. I read somewhere that the first value is correctly classified instances because of that choice, and that the second is how many errors. But how can this be a decimal number? How do you classify something 0.41 correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers here:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/What+do+those+numbers+mean+in+a+J48+tree%3F

Basically it divides up instances with missing values and that would count as a fractional instance in all the trees.

Answer (score 0):

For sample dataset: https://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs366/data/weka_files/vote.arff 
Vote.arff in Weka

Decision tree result: physician-fee-freeze = n: democrat (253.41/3.75).

First number indicated the number of correct things that reach that node. ( in this democrats) and the second number after “/” shows number of incorrect things that reach that node ( in this case republicans)

Total number of instances: 435
Total number of no (also integral number of correct things): 253
Probability of having no: 253/435 = 0.58

Total number of missing data: 11
Total number of times where it is coming with “no”: 8
Probability: 8/11 = 0.72

Total probability that missing data could be no: 0.58 X 0.72 = 0.42

Total number of correct things: 253+0.42 = 253.42 ~ 253.41

The number after the “/”shows number of incorrect things that reach that node. Now if you see this data it has five incorrect instances where “republican” is the result while “physician fee freeze” is “n” (or “?”)

Those five can be split as following:
Total number incorrect instances with “n” : 2
Total number incorrect instances with “?”: 3

Similar formula:

2+(253/435)*3=3.75